# what kind of XAML style for these custom buttons?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to create side-buttons in WPF. the Back and Forward on the picture.

[image]

I cannot figure out what kind of style should I create for their shape? I already have central button all I need to build up others with such unusual shape. Could anybody help with any ideas about their ControlTemplate?

Comment: Have you tried using a custom button template ?

Comment: This is not a single button, its 3 buttons. You could create a UserControl or CustomControl, which consists of 3 Buttons. Your User/Custom Control then needs 3 dependency properties for the 3 different commands, that are attached to each distinct button. Now for the design. You just override the whole ControlTemplate. If your question is more like "how to do it graphically", i can't help i'm a programmer not a designer :) Usually it has something todo with GradiantBrushes, Pathes for the Icons, Borders and Shapes and all that designer hokus pokus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround to use negative margins for both side buttons so that Play would overlapped them.

Comment: Playing with margin/padding is bad design. Use a grid! (or any other built in panel)